# Unable to click on Text link - Observed "InvalidSelectorException" & "Compound class names not permitted"

Tags: selenium, c#, chromedriver

[image][image][image]

Please find image, that I want to click on.
Functionality of image is dropdown button. By clicking on v,+ and on name will get drop down.

I used this code:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CommandBarItem beak-anchor command is-focused")).Click();
```

Getting an error that compound class names are not permitted

Please can any help?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Not able to understand your problem. Can you give more details about your HTML and the scripts that you are using? and also maybe a screenshot of the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

For locating elements using the ClassName you are not allowed to use compund class names. For example, in your case the element has 3 CSS classes and when you enter all of them in the `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("` it is considered as a compound class name. This means that, it is considered as single class with spaces, which is not allowed in locating element with ClassName.

Use a single class name to locate your element. If it doesn't have a unique class, then use CSSSelector (something like 
`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name='CommandBarItem']"));`) or an even better option would be to use **XPath**. You can get the XPath of the target element using the **FirePath** extension of **Mozilla FireFox**.

---

**Addendum As per the updates in the Question,**

You want to test whether clicking one of the 3 links (+, New and v) will open a drop down list or not.

BUT

With your test script you are trying to click the div that encloses the 3 links and not the links themselves.

You should test each of the three links separately. Try,

Clicking **+** icon:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CommandBarItem-Icon")).Click();
```

Clicking **NEW** link:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("CommandBarItem-CommandText")).Click();
```

Clicking **v** (down arrow):

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("od-CommandBarItem-down")).Click();
```

**OR TRY**

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("od-CommandBarItem-link")).Click();
```

You can try the same with **CSSSelector** or with **XPath** as well. Just remember, DON'T TRY TO CLICK THE DIV. CLICK THE LINKS THAT HAVE AN ACTION TO OPEN DROP DOWN LIST WRITTEN ON.

Comment: Even I tried with Xpath and css selector, Error unable to locate element

Comment: You know like I asked in an earlier comment on the question, if we could see your HTML (target) and the test scripts, it'll be better for us to help!

Comment: <span class="CommandBarItem-icon" data-bind="component: { name: 'od-icon-glyph', params: { icon: $parent.icon, badge: $parent.iconBadge } }, attr: { 'is-flipped': $parent.positionIconRight }"><i class="od-IconGlyph ms-Icon ms-Icon--Add od-IconGlyph--visible" data-bind="classes: { base: iconClasses, mappings: { 'od-IconGlyph--badged': badge, 'od-IconGlyph--visible': icon } }, with: badge"></i></span>

Comment: That's half of what I asked for. Now would you be kind and share the other half? Better yet share screenshots of your application HTML AND THE SCRIPT YOU ARE USING TO TEST IT.

Comment: Please find question with updated image

Comment: The image you have updated and your selenium code in the question clearly shows that you are using wrong CSS class name for locating the element! So, its quite obvious you will get element not found error. You want to access a span with css class name: CommandBarItem-icon and instead of this, you are looking for a composite class in your selenium script with "CommandBarItem beak-anchor command is-focused".

Comment: Yes I used composite class name, again same error- Compound class names are not allowed. can you suggest me any other way to do this?.

Comment: See now, that's the problem. People here are trying to tell you not to use composite class names and you're continuing to use composite class names!

Comment: But I tried with Xpath and cssselector also

Comment: I've updated my answer as per the updates you provided in the question. Check that out. Let me know if it works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a compound class,And compound classes cant be used in

`driver.FindElement(By.ClassName`

Try some other way to find the element or use the **CSSSelector**.

Compound means it contain spaces inside your class name.But selenium is only looking for class names which don't have any spaces in between the class name.

- If really needed to club class names, I will suggest to use "."[dot] in between two class names

Comment: Even this is also class name without spaces."CommandBarItem-link"

Answer (score 0):

OK, Use Firefox Selenium IDE to perform the same thing.
After recording the step please review the code and check how does Selenium IDE capture that element.

1. Download FireFox
2. Download and install Selenium IDE.
3. Record the steps that you have the issue with "Unable to click on
   Text link - Observed “InvalidSelectorException” & “Compound class
   names not permitted”"
4. After sucsussfully recording the step try play back the steps.
5. If it successfully playing back then go to Options ->Format and
   select c# /Nunit/Webdriver.
6. Then click on "source" tab at the main screen.
7. There you can find the exact way selenium IDE use to find that
   elemant.

The code you can see a the Source section is compatible with c# so you can use the same code on your c# project.

Comment: Okay, and then what's to be done? Can you give more info on the solution you're suggesting?

Comment: Download FireFox
Download and install Selenium IDE.
Record the steps that you have the issue with "Unable to click on Text link - Observed “InvalidSelectorException” & “Compound class names not permitted”"
After sucsussfully recording the step try play back the steps.
If it successfully playing back then go to Options ->Format and select c# /Nunit/Webdriver.
Then click on "source" tab at the main screen.
There you can find the exact way selenium IDE use to find that elemant.

Comment: Okay, now add this to your answer by editing it. Also append after getting the locator from Selenium IDE how to convert it to the Webdriver code!

Comment: Thanks @TESTasy :) for showing me the correct path for posting a better answer .